# Unable to use fwmark on Debian 11 (bulleyes) to change routing behavior

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, iproute2

I have a recipe I already use on many cases, but this time doesn't works on Debian 11 (kernel 5.10.0-10-amd64)

my setup is basically an internal interface eth0 for a RFC1918 LAN, and two external interfaces connected to some ISP's Box:

eth1 for ISP1 as default router at 10.0.0.254 with public IP 1.2.3.4 (figuratively)

eth2 for ISP2 has a router at 10.0.3.254 with public 2.3.4.5

I have different possible route. I want to control which route my packet takes, so I create some rule and fwmark. First I append  `2<tab>secondrouter` in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x3 lookup secondrouter
ip route add default via 10.0.3.254 table secondrouter
```

everythings is fine regarding `ip route list table secondrouter` and `ip rule list`

at this time I am able to do:

```
curl -4 ifconfig.me
1.2.3.4 #<- public ip address of my default route
```

Then I do

```
iptables-legacy -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 34.117.59.81 -j MARK --set-mark 0x3
```

now if I do

```
curl -4 ifconfig.me
<timeout>
```

Where I expected 2.3.4.5 as public IP.
So clearly the marked packet do not take the route from the ip route table, worse, it timeouts.

If I do this exactly the same way on older Debian, its works perfectly.

NB:if I do a

```
ip route add 34.117.59.81 via <second router IP>
```

my curl test works perfectly as expected

```
curl -4 ifconfig.me
2.3.4.5 #<- Pub ip address of my second router
```

My problem occurs when using `iptables` or `iptables-legacy` to mark packets to route.
BTW I have plenty of iptables rules that works fine, so it do not looks like an iptables issue.

```
iptables-legacy-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jan 23 22:35:06 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [41:5019]
:INPUT ACCEPT [41:5019]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [44:4752]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [44:4752]
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 34.117.59.81/32 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x3/0xffffffff
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jan 23 22:35:06 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jan 23 22:35:06 2022
*filter
:INPUT DROP [19:7746]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [846:62420]
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 10.0.6.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.6.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jan 23 22:35:06 2022
```

Comment: Please add output of `iptables-save` to the question.

Comment: @tero-kilkanen ... done

Answer (score 0):

When the packet get out of the machine it is given a source IP address corresponding to the default output interface.

So it is required to add a MASQUERADE rule on the output interface because the mark rules gives our packet another destination than the planned one.

```
iptables-legacy -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

for the sake of understanding netfilter order of processing : (via [Plouf](http://www.plouf.fr.eu.org/bazar/netfilter/schema_netfilter.txt))

```
                     (input interface)
                             |
                             v
                     /-------+-------\
                     | sanity checks |
                     \-------+-------/
                             |
                             v hook NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING
                      +------+------+
                      | conntrack   |
                      | defrag.     |
                      +-------------+
                      | mangle      |
                      | PREROUTING  |
                      +-------------+
                      | nat (dst)   |
                      | PREROUTING  |
                      +------+------+
                             |
                             v
        local delivery  /----+----\    forward
       +---------------+   route   +---------------+
       |                \---------/                |
       v                                           v
 /-----+-----\                               /-----+-----\
 |  defrag.  |                               | TTL check |
 \-----+-----/                               | dec. TTL  |
       |                                     \-----+-----/
       v hook NF_IP_LOCAL_IN                       |
+------+------+                                    |
| mangle  (1) |                                    |
| INPUT       |                                    |
+-------------+                                    |
| filter      |                                    v
| INPUT       |                              /-----+-----\
+-------------+                              | DF check  |
| nat (src)(2)|                              \-----+-----/
+-------------+                                    |
| conntrack   |                                    |
| confirm     |                                    | 
+------+------+                               hook v NF_IP_FORWARD
       |                                    +------+------+
       v                                    | mangle  (1) |
/------+--------\                           | FORWARD     |
| local process |                           +-------------|
\------+--------/                           | filter      |
       |                                    | FORWARD     |
       v                                    +------+------+
 /-----+-----\                                     |
 |   route   |                                     |
 |   frag.   |                                     |
 \-----+-----/                                     |
       |                                           |
       v hook NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT                      |
+------+------+                                    |
| conntrack   |                                    |
| defrag.     |                                    |
+-------------+                                    |
| mangle      |                                    |
| OUTPUT      |                                    |
+-------------+                                    v
| nat (dst)(3)|                              /-----+-----\
| OUTPUT      |                              |   frag.   |
+-------------+                              \-----+-----/
| filter      |                                    |
| OUTPUT      |                                    |
+------+------+                                    |
       |                                           |
       v                                           |
 /-----+-----\                                     |
 |  reroute  |                                     |
 \-----+-----/                                     |
       |                                           |
       +------------------+     +------------------+
                          |     |
                          v     v hook NF_IP_POST_ROUTING
                      +---+-----+---+
                      | mangle  (1) |
                      | POSTROUTING |
                      +-------------+
                      | nat (src)   |
                      | defrag.     |
                      | POSTROUTING |
                      +-------------+
                      | conntrack   |
                      | confirm     |
                      | frag.       |
                      +------+------+
                             |
                             v
                   (output interface)
```